# What's the difference between standard java data structures and Java Collections Framework?

Tags: java

JCF allows faster traversing(looping) thru a data structure.

It's built-in, other than that, what are the advantages of having JCF instead of using regular Array, LinkedList etc?

Comment: "JCF allows faster traversing(looping) thru a data structure" -  any references?

Comment: Or I don't understand you correctly... do you mean fast in terms of access time or in terms of convenient code?

Comment: The JCF is written in Java ... so ... how would the JCF not be Java data structures?

Comment: In particular, `LinkedList` *is* a part of the JCF.

Comment: @Lars convenient code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [release notes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) The first paragraph is the most important one. Especially **reducing programming effort**.

> The Java platform includes a collections framework. A collection is an
>   object that represents a group of objects (such as the classic Vector
>   class). A collections framework is a unified architecture for
>   representing and manipulating collections, enabling collections to be
>   manipulated independently of implementation details.
>
> The primary advantages of a collections framework are that it:
>
> **Reduces programming effort** by providing data structures and algorithms so you don't have to write them yourself.
>
> **Increases performance** by providing high-performance implementations of data structures and algorithms. Because the various
>   implementations of each interface are interchangeable, programs can be
>   tuned by switching implementations.
>
> **Provides interoperability** between unrelated APIs by establishing a common language to pass collections back and forth.
>       Reduces the effort required to learn APIs by requiring you to learn multiple ad hoc collection APIs.
>
> **Reduces the effort required to design and implement APIs** by not requiring you to produce ad hoc collections APIs.
>
> **Fosters software reuse** by providing a standard interface for collections and algorithms with which to manipulate them.

The collections framework consists of:

> **Collection interfaces.** Represent different types of collections, such as sets, lists, and maps. These interfaces form the
>   basis of the framework.
>
> **General-purpose implementations.** Primary implementations of the collection interfaces.
>
> **Legacy implementations.** The collection classes from earlier releases, Vector and Hashtable, were retrofitted to implement the
>   collection interfaces.
>
> **Special-purpose implementations.** Implementations designed for use in special situations. These implementations display nonstandard
>   performance characteristics, usage restrictions, or behavior.
>       Concurrent implementations. Implementations designed for highly concurrent use.
>
> **Wrapper implementations.** Add functionality, such as synchronization, to other implementations.
>       Convenience implementations. High-performance "mini-implementations" of the collection interfaces.
>
> **Abstract implementations.** Partial implementations of the collection interfaces to facilitate custom implementations.
>
> **Algorithms.** Static methods that perform useful functions on collections, such as sorting a list.
>
> **Infrastructure.** Interfaces that provide essential support for the collection interfaces.
>
> **Array Utilities.** Utility functions for arrays of primitive types and reference objects. Not, strictly speaking, a part of the
>   collections framework, this feature was added to the Java platform at
>   the same time as the collections framework and relies on some of the
>   same infrastructure.